# Angular + Rails app hang up whole browser when trying to fetch subpage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, asset-pipeline, pushstate

I'm writing application using Angular and Rails. I have fallback in my `ApplicationController`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  before_filter :intercept_html_requests

  private

  def intercept_html_requests
    render('pages/index') if request.format == Mime::HTML
  end
end
```

And router like:

```
betly.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

  $routeProvider.when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'assets/tournaments.html',
    controller: 'tournamentController'
  }).when('/aaa', {
    templateUrl: 'assets/tournaments.html',
    controller: 'tournamentController'
  }).when('/matches/:matchId',{
    templateUrl: 'assets/matchDetails.html',
    controller: 'matchController'
  }).otherwise({
    redirectTo:'/'
  });
});
```

`views/layouts/application.html.erb`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app>
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <title>BetLy</title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all" %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  </head>
  <body>
    <%= yield %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  </body>
</html>
```

And when I'm trying to go to `/matches/10` the browser infinitely download assets. Why and how to fix that?

Comment: I am experiencing same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in routes file. When you are trying to catch all routes in your Rails app then you shouldn't add `/` in route, so it should look like:

```
match '*any', to: 'controller#method'
```

instead of

```
match '/*any', to: 'controller#method'
```